# Google Maps API JS V3 included but not working

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, google-maps-api-3, laravel-blade

I included in my laravel app the GOOGLE MAPS V3 API to work with. I placed the script into my header of the HTML document like this:

```
<head>
    <!-- Store Meta information -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link href="{{ asset('/css/main.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Import Scripts  -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={{ Config::get('customconfig.googleMapsApiKey')}}"></script>
    <title>MEDIFAKTOR</title>
</head>
```

And a custom JS file before the closing BODY tag in the blade Template that looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<!-- Head Data -->
@include('includes.head')
<body>
<!-- Header -->
<header class="main-header">
    <a class="logo" href=""><b>MEDIFAKTOR</b>server</a>
    @include('includes/navBar')
</header>

<!-- Body -->
<div class="pageContainer">
    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div class="pageSidebarWrapper">
        @include('includes.sidebar')
    </div>
    <!-- Content -->
    <div class="pageContentWrapper">
        <div class="pageContent">
            <div class="mapcanvas"></div>
            @include('includes.content')
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/googleMaps.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**googleMaps.js**

```
var map;
function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapcanvas'),
        mapOptions);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

When I load the page, I get the error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null
```

As far as I read so far, this usually occurs, when the page is not fully loaded or the div container class I am searching for in the JS script is non existent. Both I think I can exclude as an option. But still the error occurs.

Is there a special loading order of files in Laravel that affects the loading of the include files in the blade template? Or did I miss out something else?

Thank you,

Sebastian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in your code doesn't have any element id="mapcanvas" 
in your html code change

```
<div class="mapcanvas"></div>
```

change to

```
<div id="mapcanvas"></div>
```

Does you have **css** to set heigth and width off **mapcanvas**

```
#mapcanvas{
    height: 400px;
    witdh: 500px;

}
```

Comment: Thank you. That solved the issue. But there is no map displayed after loading. The code is from the google dev page. Should there be more information being provided to display a map for a start?

Comment: I just got it.. no width and height on the div element! Thank you!!

Comment: get css to set witdh and height off **<div id="mapcanvas"></div>**